# react-redux useEffect with array as dependency not always updated

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, fetch-api

I am developing a application with React and Redux.
To be efficient we normalise the data into the store. (`store[OBJECT_TYPE].byId`)

My problem is when I have object which have multiple dependencies. I have to dispatch the Redux action to fetch the data from the rest API.

With the useEffect dependency array:
 - If I add the array `artistIds` some components aren't updated/re-rendered once the artist is loaded.
 - If I don't add the `artistIds` I have a ugly warning (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps) but it's working.

What is the best practice here ?
 - Add a comment `//eslint-disable-next-line` to remove the warning.
 - Create a component `ArtistLink` which is going to handle the dispatch by himself. (In this case I'll have a lot of single fetch instead of few)

Here an example of code to illustrate the problem (song have one to many artists).

```js
function SongCard({ id, name, artistIds = [], ...}) {

    const artists = useSelector(state => artistIds.map(id => state.artists.byId[id] || {}));

    useEffect(() => {
        if (artistIds.length > 0) {
            dispatch(reduxArtistsActions.get(artistIds));
        }
    }, [dispatch, artistIds]); // Here is the problem - With artistIds the re-rendered isn't always correct
    ...

    return <>
        ...
        {artists.map(artist => <a href={artist.id}>{artist.name}</a>)}
        ...
    </>
}
```

Comment: "React guarantees that dispatch function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list." https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer